# Add icon before text (multiple lines) css

Tags: html, css

I want to add an icon before the `<p>` tag, the content of this p tag is multiple lines. But I have an issue that the distance between the first line and second line is too big, because the icon must be larger than text.

```css
p::before {
  content: "0";
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Ducksburg</p>
<div class="abc">
  <p><b>Note:</b> For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declavvhjhg hgcs ggdg gyfc vuiu uuhc uiugc uhgc jjvv juvvh hjvvred, and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:before instead of ::before).</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just change the `:before` element position to absolute, left: 0, top: 50%, transform: translateY(-50%)

Answer (score 0):

Add absolute positioned  before content inside relative positioned p tag with a min height of 110px;

```css
p::before {
  content: "0";
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  padding-left: 80px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<p>My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Ducksburg</p>
<div class="abc">
  <p><b>Note:</b> For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declavvhjhg hgcs ggdg gyfc vuiu uuhc uiugc uhgc jjvv juvvh hjvvred, and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:before instead of ::before).</p>
</div>
```